# Passing Javascript Array to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to create a simple shopping cart with JavaScript and PHP. I have created a list of items with order buttons and when pressed adds information about the item to an array in Javascript called cart[]. I want to be able to pass this array to a new PHP page when the user hits the submit button. Any ideas?

```
var cart = [];

function push() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "assign7b.php",
            data: {x: cart},
        });
    }

function add1() {
        var shoe1 = ['<?php echo $names[0]?>', '<?php echo $images[0]?>', '<?php echo $stocks[0]?>', '<?php echo $prices[0]?>'];
        cart.push(shoe1);
    }
```

This is what I have so far. The function add1() adds an array of strings to the cart array. The function push() is meant to pass the array to the 'assign7b.php' page.

Comment: That won't work.  Want to pass client-side data to the server?  You'll need to do some kind of HTTP request with that data attached.  That's what AJAX is about (there are other ways).

Comment: If you want to display the new PHP page, you wouldn't need JavaScript. You could create a form specifying the file path as the value for the action attribute. Like this: `<form action="assign7b.php">...</form>`, and inside the form you'd add the elements that you need to send (including hidden one, if that is necessary).